# Concatenating Files based on first characters of file names

Tags: linux, shell-script, filenames

In a folder I have files like below.

```
COUNTRY_US_20200401.TXT
COUNTRY_GB_20200401.TXT
COUNTRY_FR_20100328.TXT
COUNTRY_US_20200406.TXT
COUNTRY_GB_20200410.TXT
```

I want to check for first 10 characters and if file names are matching then I want to concatenate files like below
`COUNTRY_US.TXT` (`COUNTRY_US_20200401.TXT` and `COUNTRY_US_20200406.TXT` will be merged)

```
COUNTRY_GB.TXT
COUNTRY_FR.TXT
```

I can hard code the file names and I can concatenate but problem is if tomorrow a new file arrived with name `COUNTRY_GR_20200319.TXT` how can I merge the files and I want the individual files to be deleted at end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rm -f COUNTRY_??.TXT
for file in COUNTRY_??_*.TXT; do
    cat "$file" >>"${file%_*.TXT}.TXT"
done
```

This first makes sure that there are no merged files.  We will always *append* to the merged files, so if such files already exists, the data in the result files may be duplicated if the code is run multiple times.

We then iterate over the files.  We assume that each file matches the pattern `COUNTRY_??_*.TXT` (which the names in the question seems to do).  For each file, we simply use `cat` to append the data to the end of the corresponding merged file.  The name of the merged file is had by first removing the shortest suffix string matching `_*.TXT` from the filename, and then adding `.TXT` back to the end.

Testing this:

```
$ ls
COUNTRY_FR_20100328.TXT   COUNTRY_GB_20200410.TXT   COUNTRY_US_20200406.TXT
COUNTRY_GB_20200401.TXT   COUNTRY_US_20200401.TXT
```

(the loop is run here)

```
$ ls
COUNTRY_FR.TXT            COUNTRY_GB_20200401.TXT   COUNTRY_US_20200401.TXT
COUNTRY_FR_20100328.TXT   COUNTRY_GB_20200410.TXT   COUNTRY_US_20200406.TXT
COUNTRY_GB.TXT            COUNTRY_US.TXT
```

Each new file will be the concatenation of the corresponding files with dates in their names.

---

With extra requirements added in comments: Remove headers from all but the first merged file.

```sh
rm -f COUNTRY_??.TXT
for file in COUNTRY_??_*.TXT; do
    outfile=${file%_*.TXT}.TXT
    if [ -s "$outfile" ]; then
        sed 1d "$file"
    else
        cat "$file"
    fi >>"$outfile"
done
```

That is, if the output file exists and has a size greater than zero, strip the first line from the current file using `sed`, otherwise just use `cat` as before.

Comment: Perfectly working fine . But when we merge files how can remove the headers of files. I only want the headers in line 1 but not of merged files

Comment: @user1024962 See updated answer. This should ideally have been part of the original question.